# How to connect to mySQL server in VERIFY-IDENTITY mode with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

mySQL supports several SSL modes: DISABLED, PREFERRED, REQUIRED, VERIFY-CA, and VERIFY-IDENTITY but I'm unclear as to how mysqli implements them.

The mysqli->real_connect method provides a MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL flag described as "Use SSL (encryption)" but if the flag is not used, is the mode set to DISABLED or PREFERRED?

If the flag is used, I can specify the CA Cert file using the ssl_set method but how do I specify that I want VERIFY-CA or VERIFY-IDENTITY mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mysqli_real_connect() function.
Make sure pass the MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL flag aswell.

Here is some example code for you too.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
$mysqli->ssl_set("/path/to/client-key.pem", "/path/to/client-cert.pem", "/path/to/ca.pem", "/path/to/ca-bundle.pem", NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that solves my problem. I want the connection to use the mySQL VERIFY-IDENTITY ssl mode. If I set the MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL and supply the path to the CA cert file, there are two possibilities, to connect using VERIFY-CA mode (=verify the certificate authenticity) or VERIFY-IDENTITY mode (which also verifies the certificate authenticity but also verifies that the host name in the certificate is the host I specify when opening the connection), but PHP doesn't seem to provide a way to enforce VERIFY-IDENTITY mode, which is what I want to use.